# Users cannot change e-mail address in SonarQube

Tags: email, sonarqube

For some reason, in our SonarQube installation users cannot configure or change their e-mail address. When any user clicks on "My profile", the "Email:" entry is displayed, but not changeable.

Only an administrator user can change users' addresses through "Settings - Security - Users - Edit" - but even an admin cannot change his own address on the "My profile" page.

I looked through the config pages, the config files, the docs and around here, and we seem to be the only ones having this problem. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Are you using LDAP integration?

Comment: No. We do have the LDAP plugin in the plugins folder, but none of the settings listed [here](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin) are configured in `sonar.properties`.